# DetailView in TableView doesn't work (IOS)

Tags: iphone, controller, tableview

I'm starting with a program that has a Tabbar controller with 4 buttons.
On one of the pages there is a table view in the viewController. And when I click the row I want to push a DetailView. But nothing happens, no errors nothing???

Anybody an idea what can be wrong?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //Get the selected item
   NSString *selectedItem = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
   DetailViewController *myController = [[DetailViewController alloc] 
                         initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" 
                     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   myController.title = @"Detail View";
   myController.selectedItem = selectedItem;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];

   [myController release];
}
```

Comment: is your above method being called ? put break point and check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have set the `UITabelViewDelegate`? If not please set the delegate of the `UITableView` as

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Also make sure your header file implements the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol

Answer (score 1):

Navigation to another View Controller is only can take place when your application supports **UINavigation Controller**. If It is there then secondly Your **UITableViewDelegates** are not there.

For this you need to have

**tableView.delegate = self;**

Or please elaborate your problem more